# I wonder if the sentence is grammatically correct? "I wonder who it was defined man as a rational animal." Am I missing something?

Tags: usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

So, I was reading "The Picture of Dorian Gray" by Oscar Wilde and stumbled across this sentence:

> **I wonder who it was defined man as a rational animal.** It was the most premature definition ever given. Man is many things, but he is not rational.

When I look at this sentence, I want to remake it into "I wonder who it was **who** defined man as a rational animal." Would it not be correct so? As I am quite used to seeing sentences like "He was the one who knew the truth.", or "It was he who called you."
Or is "it was" here used not in its regular meaning?

I'm asking this because when I take out the "it was" part, the sentence sounds pretty much fine to me,  "I wonder who defined man as a rational animal."

Comment: It's the same "optional relativiser" as *I wonder **what** it was [**that**] made it happen,*  except [that] because the "object" is a *person*, the optional relativiser can be either ***who*** or ***that*** (or *<nothing>*, because it's *optional*). Hence *I wonder who it was **that** defined man as a rational animal* is also fine.

Comment: See plenty of written instances of [*...asked who it was **who...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asked+who+it+was+who%22) and [*...asked who it was **that...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22asked+who+it+was+that%22). Probably every one of which could have ***who*** swapped for ***that*** or vice-versa without making any difference at all.

Comment: "who it was ***that*** defined man" sounds much better to me.

Comment: The sentence is correct.  There is an omitted "that".   I wonder who it was [that] defined . . .  This may seem a little strange today if you are unfamiliar with this kind of construction, but you have to remember that Ocar Wilde was writing about 130 years ago.  English has changed somewhat in the last 130 years!  If you are going to read classic works of English literature, you need to be aware of this.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for the warning! I fear I may require this foreknowledge before I venture into my next novel, having just finished "The Picture of Dorian Gray". I am now curious just how much more of such intricacies English still has in store for me!

Comment: @FallenEmpire - oh, I can assure you there will be lots in store for you!!  The further back in time you go, the more challenges you will face. Although, perhaps don't start with Chaucer in the original Middle English LOL ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer (tl;dr):**

When Wilde was writing it was already literary and old-fashioned to use a relative clause without a relative word like *who* or *that* if the clause did not have its own subject. In modern standard English, the Original Poster is correct that the clause would need to be introduced by  *who* or *that*. Oscar Wilde's sentence would be ungrammatical in modern standard English if written today.

However, this type of sentence was very common indeed in Shakespeare's day. And like many aspects of early modern English, this type of sentence lives on in regional varieties of English. So you may hear interesting sentences like these in various different situations

---

**Full answer:**

In modern standard English, when a relative clause contains an expressed subject, we can omit the relative pronoun (except in the case of *whose*). In such cases, the relative pronoun most often represents the object of the relative clause. However, when the relative pronoun is co-indexed with the *subject* of the clause (or actually *is* the subject, depending on how you interpret the grammar) it is not possible to omit it.

1. *That is the woman (<s>who</s>) he loves.*
2. **That is the woman (<s>who</s>) loves him.* (ungrammatical).

In the example above above we see that in (1), where *who* is interpreted as the object of the relative clause, we can omit it. However in (2), where *who* would represent the subject of *loves*, it cannot be omitted. [Note however, In some non-standard dialects of English (2) would be perfectly grammatical].

However, this is only true about present day standard English. In early modern English it was very common to omit the pronoun is sentences such as (2), probably more common than to omit them in sentences such as (1). In Shakespeare's day the omission of relative pronouns was becoming rarer, but still occurred. He himself used bare relative clauses without pronouns reasonably frequently.

**The Original Poster's Question - Modern English:**

The Original Poster's sentence is from Oscar Wilde's novel *The Picture of Dorian Grey*. Wilde had a very literary style, and often liked to use fairly archaic language. Even in Wilde's day the sentence was a little bit archaic and had a literary effect:

> *I wonder who it was defined man as a rational animal.*

This is a complicated sentence. For a start the matrix clause consists of the following main parts:

- Subject - *I* - pronoun
- Predicator - *wondered* - verb
- Complement - *who it was defined man as a rational animal* - subordinate open interrogative clause.

Because the interrogative clause is subordinate it does not have the same word order as it would in a main clause. Here is the main clause version of that same clause:

3. *Who was it defined man as a rational animal?*

Further complicating matters is that this is an interrogative version of a special type of sentence called an *it*-cleft. Let's make it less complicated by turning it into a normal declarative clause instead of a question. We'll use 'X' to stand in for the question word *who*:

4. *It was X defined man as a rational animal.*

We can substitute 'X' with '*the teacher*' to make a complete version of the  sentence:

5. *It was the teacher defined man as a rational animal.* [ungrammatical in modern English]

We can make it simpler still by removing the extra information *as a rational animal*:

6. *It was the teacher defined man. [ungrammatical in modern English]

This is a basic *it*-cleft construction that we have made easier to  examine by making it a main clause and by making it declarative. A regular cleft sentence has four main parts: a dummy subject, the meaningless word *it*; a form of specifying *BE*, in this case the word *was*; a noun phrase (NP), in this case *the teacher*; and a relative clause, in this case *defined man as a rational animal*, which gives us more information about the noun phrase.

Unlike a normal relative clause construction, the relative clause and the noun phrase do not make a single large noun phrase. They are two separate parts of the clause. Nonetheless, the relative clause has the same rules that a normal relative clause has when it is attached to its antecedent. In the following examples we can see that the relative clause has a gap in the subject position.

7. *I don't like the teacher **who** [<s>he</s> defined man as rational].*
8. *I don't like the teacher **that** [<s>he</s> defined man as rational].*
9. **I don't like the teacher [<s>he</s> defined man as rational].*

In modern English, the rules for relative clauses such as these allow us to omit the relative pronoun if the relative clause has its own subject, but not if it doesn't. For this reason (9) is ungrammatical. The following sentence in contrast would be fine:

10. I don't like the man [the teacher defined <s>him</s> as irrational].

Because the relative clause has its own subject, we do not need a relative pronoun like *who* or *that* here.

Note that because the relative clause in the Original Poster's example has been mangled and worked into a number of highfaluting constructions—it's been subordinated,*it*-clefted, buried in an interrogative—it looks quite posh and  sophisticated. And for this reason may seem more grammatical than it really is.

**The Original Poster's question: Wilde's English and others'**

The Original Poster's sentence was already quite pretentious, literary and slightly archaic in Wilde's day, but relative clauses like these were still familiar enough to be considered  grammatical in standard English.

Relative clauses like the one he used in the Original poster's (subordinate open interrogative *it*-cleft) sentence, are still perfectly grammatical in many regional varieties of English, but not in the standard Englishes, such as those which are taught in schools, or learned in language schools. They are not archaic any more, they are just not grammatical in these types of English.

Of course, that does not make them any less interesting or appealing when we see them in works of art from two centuries ago, or five centuries ago or when we see them used in those  regional Englishes where they are perfectly grammatical. Enjoy them where you see them,  but don't use them in your standard English!

Comment: Oscar Wilde is a wonderful writer (Well, I've always liked his short stories) and learners would do well reading his works rather than studying today's "modern English" in many rap/hip-hop lyrics.

Comment: I can't quarrel with the technical accuracy of this analysis, but I think one can approach it from a different direction. Given the sentence "I wonder who it was who X", can one remove the ugly repetition of the word "who" without making the sentence unintelligible? And the answer, as Wilde demonstrates, is that one can.

Comment: @MichaelKay Wilde could, but  we can't because we aren't alive 140 years ago (give or take 10 years depending on which version you want).

Comment: @Araucaria We can do anything we like, whether it's grammatically correct or not. Just as Wilde and Shakespeare could.

Comment: @MichaelKay Exactly so, but it may not make the sentence less ugly to modern ears!

Answer (score 16):

> I wonder who it was defined man as a rational animal.
> I wonder who it was who defined man as a rational animal.
> I wonder who defined man as a rational animal.

Are all grammatically correct versions of the sentence and mean the same thing. In English you can omit some words if it is obvious what the meaning is. There are other posts on this site that discuss this. The original sentence is an example of just such a construct.
"The picture of Dorian Gray" was written over 130 years ago in 1890 and literary styles have changed since then. Whilst still valid, this particular omission is much less frequent in modern writing. You are more likely to find your even shorter version today.

Comment: In Shakespeare's day it was permissible to omit the relative pronoun  when it corresponded to the subject of the relative clause, but not if it corresponded to the object. In Wilde's day it was already an archaism to omit the relative pronoun when it corresponded to the subject of the relative clause. Today it is downright ungrammatical in standard Englishes, it is not simply 'archaic'. We cannot say _"*I don't like man is standing in the hall"_ . It's fully ungrammatical.

Comment: @Araucaria Not permissible to omit the pronoun if it corresponded to the object? Shakespeare does so himself (e.g., _Romeo & Juliet_ scene I: “A right good mark-man! And she's fair I love”, where the omitted pronoun is _whom_ in object position).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, quite right. Overstepped there. [See this interesting and more accurate post instead of that off the cuff comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427995/shakespearean-relative-clause-i-have-a-brother-is-condemned-to-die/428034#428034)

Answer (score 10):

> I wonder who it was defined man as a rational animal.

I agree with you that a relative pronoun is missing.

Edit

That relative pronoun is the subject of the relative clause *who defined man as a rational animal* and should not be omitted in modern usage.

> I wonder who it was [who] defined man as a rational animal.

The sentence could be simplified to become the other example you gave.

> I wonder who defined man as a rational animal.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the relative pronoun "should not be omitted". In modern English writing it is rare to do so (but still grammatically correct) but this was written over 130 years ago and styles change. You've only got to read any of the Victorian novelists to find many "odd" (archaic) sounding forms that would not be used today. This is one of them. English is an evolving language, styles and usage change.

Comment: Since both answers disagree, can we understand that the sentence is OK for Oscar Wilde in 1890 but it's not a useful model to follow for English language learners?

Comment: @Pere That sounds very apt to me. It is grammatical, but in current English, it is a structure largely limited to certain dialects. You’re not unlikely to hear it now and again, but for a learner, it’s best to think of it as something to recognise, but not emulate. Including the relative pronoun is, at any rate, always an – at least – equally correct option.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's *not* grammatical in modern English to use a bare relative clause if the subject of the clause is missing. It  was only just grammatical 130 years ago when Wilde was writing! Language learners spend hours and hours learning exactly this and being examined on it!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149509/discussion-on-answer-by-seowjooheng-singapore-i-wonder-if-the-sentence-is-gramma); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.